How to route to a specific page in Next.js when a certain API is called?
export default function handler(req, res) {
  console.log("Received Gesture");
}


This is my code in page\api folder. When the api is being called it prints in the console: "Received Gesture" but I want it also to head to a specific page in my project. How to do so?
I tried to use next/navigation but it doesn't work becs I am on the server side I think.

could you try next/link
import Link from 'next/link'
 
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <Link href="/dashboard" replace>
      Dashboard
    </Link>
  )
}

or window.location.href if u click button (not recommended) caused lead to a less smooth user experience and doesn't leverage Next.js's routing features.

Man I don't need it as a button. I want it to direct directly to a specific page in my project.

it's mean, when page mounted, i have to direct to another link, right ?
i use const router = useRouter(), and code like router.replace("./link")
